# BDD, Specifications, and "Specification Reports" with xUnit.NET?

Tags: bdd, specifications, xunit.net

I am a new, but huge fan, of the BDD approach to software development and "specification". I have been making use of [xUnit.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/xunit), [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), and an [extension to xUnit.NET](http://iridescence.no/post/Extending-xUnit-with-a-Custom-ObservationAttribute-for-BDD-Style-Testing.aspx) that allows me to perform BDD-style testing (I'm using testing loosely, as its not really so much testing as it is specifying expected behavior). Currently, I run all my tests with ReSharper, and its nice seeing my specifications spelled out in detail and green across the board.

However, now that I'm using the BDD approach on a regular basis, I want a better reporting solution that can render all of the specifications for a system in a nice format that can be referenced as a form of documentation for new devs, during future refactorings, etc.

Does anyone know of any existing tools, preferably free, that can integrate with xUnit.NET to provide a nicely formatted report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Björn Rochel's [xUnit BDD Extensions](https://github.com/chadly/xUnit-BDD-Extensions). They [include a report generator](http://www.bjoernrochel.de/2009/07/05/dude-i-can-do-reports).

Mathias

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MSpec, which has a decent report, supports xUnit [since July](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/05/mspec-take-2/).